# Change Input Value with a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I once saw an old colleague do this, but never asked how he did it.  He has hidden function where when you entered a value in a cell, it automatically ran a calculations, therefore removing the need for a separate cell to run the formula.

I have resource info in columns A and B and then Months and their number of days across the top.  The example I saw once was where you entered "1" in Cell C3, it automatically calculated ((C3*B3)*C1)), to advise what the cost was for having one resource, and so on.

[image: 1]

I think it needs a VBA script, which is beyond my skills, so hoping someone can show me how to do this, as it would be very helpful

Comment: [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Comment: I'm unsure which cell would be modified by this operation, would the result you want to see be this: the user enters a number in a cell in a specific column, and when he leave the cell this number is modified so it's the result of a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Hi) you don't necessarily need VBA to do that. Let me describe and see if it will suit your purpose.

1. Select cells where you want to hide formula
2. Go to Home - Format - Format Cells - Protection, then untick Locked and tick Hidden
3. Go to Review - Protect sheet and in the opened window input some basic password, could be just a symbol.

Check then your cells, formulas will disappear. To make formulas visible again just unprotect sheet (go to Review - Protect sheet again).

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on sheet tab > <kbd>View Code</kbd> > paste the code

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const START_ROW = 3
    Const START_COL = 3
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If .Column >= START_COL And .Row >= START_ROW Then
                If Len(.Value) > 0 And IsNumeric(.Value) _
                        And IsNumeric(Me.Cells(.Row, "B")) _
                        And IsNumeric(Me.Cells(1, .Column)) Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = .Value * Me.Cells(.Row, "B") * Me.Cells(1, .Column)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Taller: Thank you very much for this, it's great.  However my needs have expanded slightly and I'm not sure if this is allowed, but wondered if I could contact you directly and get some advice or even some paid help

Comment: SO is not a place to provide paid coding service. [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: I may contact u if you leave an email.